# Video is not showing up on custom firebase domain

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video

I'm using react for my web aplication. Importing Video from static folder like this

```
import Video from "../static/videos/Tesla4.mp4";
```

Later in the code I'm using it like this

```
<video
 loop
 preload="auto"
 playsInline
 muted
>
 <source
    src={Video}
    type="video/mp4"
  ></source>
</video>
```

I'm using firebase for deployment, I've bought a custom domain and added to the project.
On domain that is received from firebase - video is showing up
https://template-practice-88ad8.web.app/projects
But on custom domain that I've added - it's an empty area instead of video
https://tarasshynkarenko.com/projects
Why's that and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in a video tag:

```
<video controls width="400" height="300">
  <source src={Video} type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: Actually i do, sorry just got the part with source without video.
```
<video
 loop
 preload="auto"
 playsInline
 muted
>
 <source
    src={Video}
    type="video/mp4"
  ></source>
</video>
```

Comment: @Тарас did you get it working?